# Verify amount in bash

Tags: bash, if-statement, sed

Currently i'm writing a script that checks whether an amount is higher than the other.

```
if [ "324,53" -gt "325,00" ]; then
  echo "Amount is higher!"
else
  echo "Amount is lower."
fi
```

Obviously i'm receiving the error: "*integer expression expected*" when running this. I tried to use sed 's/[^0-9]*//g'` but i need the full number again for further use. Problem is that I don't know the correct way how to do this. Can anybody give some advice?

Comment: That's right! This works. Thanks! :-)

Comment: i'm not sure it worked, can you show your solution

Answer (score 1):

Bash can't handle floating point numbers. You need to use an external tool, e.g. `bc`, but you need to use decimal point, not comma:

```
if (( $(bc <<< '324.53 > 325.00') )) ; then
```

`bc` prints `1` when the condition is true, and `0` when it's false. `$(...)` takes the output of the command, and `(( ... ))` interpret it as a number, returning false for zero and true for anything else.